# Alphanumeric script breaks tabindexing

Tags: jquery, html, forms, alphanumeric

I am having an issue where I have to have an alphanumeric input field only, but the problem is it is breaking the ability to tab through the form.

```js
$(".alpha-only").on("keydown", function(event){
  // Allow controls such as backspace
  var arr = [8,16,17,20,35,36,37,38,39,40,45,46];

  // Allow letters
  for(var i = 65; i <= 90; i++){
    arr.push(i);
  }

  // Prevent default if not in array
  if(jQuery.inArray(event.which, arr) === -1){
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="alpha-only">

<input type="text">

<input type="text">
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add `9` to your array to allow the tab character:

```
var arr = [8,9,16,17,20,35,36,37,38,39,40,45,46];
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(".alpha-only").on("keydown", function(event){
  // Allow controls such as backspace
  var arr = [8,9,16,17,20,35,36,37,38,39,40,45,46];

  // Allow letters
  for(var i = 65; i <= 90; i++){
    arr.push(i);
  }

  // Prevent default if not in array
  if(jQuery.inArray(event.which, arr) === -1){
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="alpha-only">

<input type="text">

<input type="text">
```